# Python shell always starts 2 "python" processes

Tags: python, windows, read-eval-print-loop

This is a trivial question, perhaps, but I could not parse through thousands of Google "related" crap such as `threading`, `subprocess`, `multiprocess` *et alli*, so I'm going to ask anyway: on Windows 10 `cmd`, why is it that whenever I simply type `python` I get 2 python processes?

I checked with `tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq python.exe"`:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
python.exe                   25300 Console                    1      3,404 K
python.exe                    9956 Console                    1     15,552 K
```

and with SysInternals' `pslist python`:

```
Name                Pid Pri Thd  Hnd   Priv        CPU Time    Elapsed Time
python            25300   8   1   46    780     0:00:00.000     0:07:05.212
python             9956   8   1  126   8872     0:00:00.187     0:07:05.200
```

The question is not merely theoretical (although there's certainly an element to that). I'm editing a large codebase with a ton of thread leak and zombie processes and I need to know what exactly to kill without terminating other python-based services on the same machine.

Please kindly address the point. If your instinct is answering with a **question**, such as "Why do you need/want to do that?", or a **workaround**, such as "go Linux" please spare me, because:

1. why I want to know is curiosity / none of your business;
2. I am locked with Windows;
3. just like Danny Glover in Deadly Weapon, "I'm too old for this...".

Many thanks
Ricardo

Comment: This is certainly an interesting question... But I cannot reproduce on my Windows 10 box, neither with Python 3.6 nor with Python 3.8: if I start `py -3.x` or `\path\to\python.exe` I get only one line in tasklist output. Could you have a custom *relay launcher* in your path?

Comment: Thank you [Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta). I have not. Indeed, I don't even use `py` at all. I have a `poetry`-generated `.venv`, I activate it (`.venv\scripts\activate`) and they all I do is `python myApp.py`, whatever `myApp.py` might be, as long as it's there to be seen. MWE would be:
`while True: pass`. Also, I don't use `tasklist`, but rather SysInternals' `pslist`.